# PHP add JSON string in array and encode

Tags: php, json, encoding

Team,

I'm trying to generate a JSON string but I keep running into issues with (I guess) quotes.

**Code:**

```
<?php 
// JSON data generated
$attachment = "[{
   'contentType': 'application/json',
   'content': {
      'type': 'mytype',
      'body': [{
         'type': 'TextInfo',
         'text': 'TEST TEXT',
         'wrap': true
      }]
   }
}]";
// Add attachment string (JSON data) in an array
$mydata = array(
  'space' => "abc",
  'markdown' => "**welcome**",
  'attachment' => $attachment
);
// Turn array into one big JSON string
$send_json = json_encode($data2);
```

**What this should generate:**

```
{
   "space": "abc",
   "markdown": "**welcome**",
   "attachment": [{
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'content': {
         'type': 'mytype',
         'body': [{
            'type': 'TextInfo',
            'text': 'TEST TEXT',
            'wrap': true
         }]
      }
   }]
}
```

It feels like I'm missing something (besides the required knowledge ;-).

Comment: Yep, dont try and build JSON Strings manually. Create a class or array with the right contents and shape and then use `json_encode()` on it to generate the JSON String

Comment: Not sure why you want the sub objects to be in an array, as there is only one object in each case

Comment: Try typecasting `$mydata = (object)array();` that should give you an object to work with in js rather than an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how your `$attachment` data could be "*JSON data generated*" because it is invalid json ...I hope you aren't manually crafting that json string.  You should always just generate an array/object and then call `json_encode()` when you are finished populating the iterable variable with data.

- I have repaired your invalid `$attachment` string by replacing the `"` with `'` and vice versa.
- To nest this data inside `$mydata['attachment']` you will need to decode the json first.
- Finally, once your array data is completely built, THEN you call `json_encode()` on `$mydata`.  The PRETTY_PRINT flag is just to aid readability in this post.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/g2Jlo))

```
$attachment = '[{
   "contentType": "application/json",
   "content": {
      "type": "mytype",
      "body": [{
         "type": "TextInfo",
         "text": "TEST TEXT",
         "wrap": true
      }]
   }
}]';

$mydata = array(
  'space' => "abc",
  'markdown' => "**welcome**",
  'attachment' => json_decode($attachment)
);

$send_json = json_encode($mydata, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $send_json;
```

Output:

```
{
    "space": "abc",
    "markdown": "**welcome**",
    "attachment": [
        {
            "contentType": "application\/json",
            "content": {
                "type": "mytype",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextInfo",
                        "text": "TEST TEXT",
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```